# Query not giving the expected result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Model function is as below:

```
function get_newJoineesList($limit=''){ 
    $SQL ="
        SELECT userid as uid, CONCAT( firstname, ' ', lastname ) AS name,profileimage, joining_date, role as designation
        FROM pr_users_details
        INNER JOIN pr_users ON pr_users.id = pr_users_details.userid
        LEFT JOIN pr_userroles ON pr_userroles.id=pr_users.userroleid
        WHERE joining_date > DATE_SUB( NOW()-1 , INTERVAL 15 DAY )
        ORDER BY pr_users_details.id DESC";

    if($limit!=''){
        $SQL.=" LIMIT ".$limit;
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($SQL);
    $return =   $query->result_array();
    return $return;
}
```

I want to get all the results from 15 days ago to now i.e if today is 15th then retrieve all the joining date that falls between 1-15th. But somehow the above query does not work. I am also restricted to use only varchar(15) type as changing this will affect other modules. 
snapshot from db2:

[image]

snapshot from db1:

[image]

Comment: It would be great to describe **exactly** what did not work, as opposed to just simply writing "it did not work" and leave it to us to guess.

Comment: thnx for your suggestion , lost heading when edits approved , need to update again , @shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the way you store the dates do not correspond to how mysql recognizes date literals, therefore the date calculations will be incorrect. You must use the [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the strings to valid dates:

```
SELECT userid as uid, CONCAT( firstname, ' ', lastname ) AS name,profileimage, joining_date, role as designation
FROM pr_users_details
INNER JOIN pr_users ON pr_users.id = pr_users_details.userid
LEFT JOIN pr_userroles ON pr_userroles.id=pr_users.userroleid
WHERE str_to_date(joining_date,'%d-%c-%Y') > DATE_SUB( NOW()-1 , INTERVAL 15 DAY )
ORDER BY pr_users_details.id DESC
```

Also, I would consider using `curdate()` instead of `now()` because you deal with dates only, not times. Using `now()` may have interesting side effects of excluding dates that are exactly 15 days ago because of the time component.